# Simple GET request in React is not working for api call using fetch

Tags: reactjs, api, react-state

I am using newsapi to fetch news in `React` with `fetch(url)` method but at the end it returns nothing and I am not able to figure out what I am missing, since it does not show any error. My `React` code to `fetch` the json data is as below.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react"
    
    
    class App extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state ={
          totalNewsResults : null
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ totalNewsResults: data.totalResults }));
    }
      render(){
        const { totalNewsResults } = this.setState;
        return(
          <div>
            Total News results : {totalNewsResults}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default App
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: add a .catch block to your fetch, check your console for any errors or check network tab  to find the api is getting error or succeed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're destructuring the method from the `this.setState` instead of the `this.state` itself. So it's probably undefined, thus, you don't see anything.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"


class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state ={
      totalNewsResults : null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ totalNewsResults: data.totalResults }));
}
  render(){
    const { totalNewsResults } = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        Total News results : {totalNewsResults}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to destructure from setState `const { totalNewsResults } = this.setState;` which should be from state not setState.

Also add a `.catch` block to produce the error. you can check your network tab also for errors. But I think the main problem in destructuring property.

Also to show then in the DOM use `JSON.stringify(totalNewsResults)`, don't show them directly